# Android Room + Kotlin + Kapt + IntelliJ + MacOS Catalina: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, intellij-idea, kapt

Using Android Room with Kapt on MacOS Catalina, I get the following errors building the project.  The project builds successfully if I remove `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` from my `build.gradle`.

```
Failed to load native library:sqlite-3.25.2-60e239c7-424b-4b75-bfd5-b2df4aa8e01a-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib. osinfo: Mac/x86_64
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: $TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-60e239c7-424b-4b75-bfd5-b2df4aa8e01a-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib: dlopen($TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-60e239c7-424b-4b75-bfd5-b2df4aa8e01a-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    $TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-60e239c7-424b-4b75-bfd5-b2df4aa8e01a-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib: code signature in ($TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-60e239c7-424b-4b75-bfd5-b2df4aa8e01a-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
Failed to load native library:sqlite-3.25.2-79b61bc4-bdd0-4451-a523-5baa49728398-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib. osinfo: Mac/x86_64
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: $TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-79b61bc4-bdd0-4451-a523-5baa49728398-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib: dlopen($TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-79b61bc4-bdd0-4451-a523-5baa49728398-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    $TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-79b61bc4-bdd0-4451-a523-5baa49728398-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib: code signature in ($TMPDIR/sqlite-3.25.2-79b61bc4-bdd0-4451-a523-5baa49728398-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

Which produces the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8([BI)V
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(NativeDB.java:78)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:195)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:243)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:61)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:28)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:21)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:116)
    at androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier$Companion.create(DatabaseVerifier.kt:104)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:82)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:57)
    at androidx.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:134)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:985)
    ... 39 more
```

It looks like this is different from https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/97, which is the only issue I could find any information about.  Is there any way to work around this issue?

Edit:

I ended up finding [this blog post](https://silvae86.github.io/2019/04/14/how_to_reverse_engineer_database_diagrams/#macos-catalina-problems-library-validation), which led me to [this JDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223671).  I verified that `./gradlew :app:kaptDebugKotlin` worked with my JDK11, and updated IDEA to use that JDK as it's runtime, as well as telling it to execute builds with gradle instead of IDEA.  Neither of those seemed to fix the issue - running `./gradlew clean :app:kaptDebugKotlin` in my terminal with JDK11 succeeded, but running that gradle task through IDEA failed.

I ended up working around it by removing `gradle-aware make` from my run configuration, and running `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug` every time I make changes to the app.  It's a little annoying and adds an extra step, but I can still run/update the app.

Comment: Continued at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40474.

Comment: Similar issue, but in `Expo` / `React Native environment, with solution, can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909541/android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently-using-java-1-8

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - it turns out the `Gradle` setting for `Java SDK` is ignored in Android projects, and instead the `Java SDK` from the `Android SDK` is used for gradle tasks.  Setting the `Android SDK`'s `Java SDK` to JDK11 fixed the issue, because that JDK has the fix for [JDK-8223671](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223671)