# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. **EXPO.dev**

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to use the command `eas build -p android` to build my android `.aab` file, but each time I'm trying to do so, then I'm finding the error

```
 Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

After checking the build on `https://expo.dev/accounts/xyz/projects/abc/builds/abababababa...` I'm finding the error in the title with the whole logs below:

```
Running './gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
Unzipping /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.2-all/260hg96vuh6ex27h9vo47iv4d/gradle-7.2-all.zip to /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.2-all/260hg96vuh6ex27h9vo47iv4d
Set executable permissions for: /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.2-all/260hg96vuh6ex27h9vo47iv4d/gradle-7.2/bin/gradle
Welcome to Gradle 7.2!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Toolchain support for Scala
 - More cache hits when Java source files have platform-specific line endings
 - More resilient remote HTTP build cache behavior
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
[stderr] > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
[stderr]    > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
[stderr]      You can try some of the following options:
[stderr]        - changing the IDE settings.
[stderr]        - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[stderr]        - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 48s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. The whole state of the virtual file system has been discarded. Reason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

There are online resources showing how to fix it in the `Android Studio`, but anyone knows how to fix this when your build is being triggered by `expo.dev`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by adding into `eas.json`:

```
"production": {
  "android": {
    "image" : "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want more information about this EAS configuration, you can find it here: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/#android-server-images