# Eas build brokes the app, when classic expo build works just fine

Tags: react-native, expo

i have a problem with eas build (expo), My app size is about ~60mb (using expo build:android), and that build is working just fine, (I'am using physically phone).

I've build the same app, no changes, with eas build, there is a crash.

How i run eas build: `eas build -p android --profile preview`
How i run expo build: `expo build:android -t apk`

I want to point, I'am not getting any errors when Grandle is runned, and build is just fine

There is my eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
      
    "preview": {

      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
        
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.48.2"
  }
}
```

How can i check the log of crash?
Does someone had something similar?
Maybe diffrent solution to make app smaller?

Comment: I got same error. I don't know how to debug. expo SDK 45.0.0. Build show no error. App crash in physical device.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, if an environment variable was missing on first screen the app would crash.

The problem was that I had my variables in an `.env` file, which will work for the classic build but doesn't in eas build.

If that's your case, you'll need to declare your environment variables in your eas.json file, or create a secret for your app through expo's website for sensitive values.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe any logs?

I've had 1 problem regarding [Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. **EXPO.dev**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909541/android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently-using-java-1-8/72174730#72174730) and I'm working with `Firebase`, then the problem was about `.gitignore` having `google-service.json` and `.env`, which as per [this comment](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4379#issuecomment-1129614163) are not uploaded in the `EAS` Build.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and working through debugging.

Here's a good place to start -- if you're on mac, connect an android device and run:

```
adb logcat '*:S' ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

This will help you log relevant errors and debug the issue. Simply running `adb logcat` logs an unmanageably large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue and the answer are actually in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947417/react-native-dotenv-doesnt-work-with-eas-builds), but I'll outline it here briefly.

I had the same issue with undefined `.env` variables. The issue is that the files in your `.gitignore` file aren't uploaded to eas machine that assembles your build. But you can create `.easignore` file that would be a copy of your `.gitignore` file excluding your `.env` file.