# react-native-dotenv doesn't work with EAS builds

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

We used `dotenv` lib with classic builds and it worked fine providing a possibility to manage different environments. But it stopped working when we moved to EAS builds.

What are possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replace `dotenv` with a combination of `direnv` tool and EAS secrets but then I accidentally found [this file](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/eas-build-archive.md) in Expo github repo. It seems like creating `.easignore` file copying `.gitignore` file excluding env files makes `dotenv` work with EAS.

Answer (score 1):

react-native-dotenv maintainer here. Be careful NOT to commit `.env` to git. This is a major security risk. `.env` files are in `.gitignore` for a very good reason. Instead, [the EAS documentation says](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#secrets-on-the-expo-website) :

> To create app-specific secrets, navigate to the "Secrets" tab in your project dashboard.

Comment: No one say here to commit `.env` files to git